# How to get a Linq query to order results based on the order of arguments in a method signature

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a linq to sql query in my web application. I just realized that it is sorting the results by ascending based on the employee number. Is there anyway to just make it return the results in the order they are supplied?

My code is below:

```
 public static queryClass[] GetEmpData(int empID1, int empID2, int empID3, int empID4, int empID5, int empID6, int empID7, int empID8, int empID9, int empID10)
    {

        using(var context = new EmpInfoDataContext())
        {
            var query = from e in context.EmployeeMasters
                        join j in context.JobClasses on e.JobClass equals j.JobClass
                        where e.EmployeeNo == empID1 || e.EmployeeNo == empID2 || e.EmployeeNo == empID3 || e.EmployeeNo == empID4 || e.EmployeeNo == empID5 || e.EmployeeNo == empID6 || e.EmployeeNo == empID7 || e.EmployeeNo == empID8 || e.EmployeeNo == empID9 || e.EmployeeNo == empID10
                        select new queryClass{firstName = e.FirsName, lastName = e.LastName, employeeNo = e.EmployeeNo, department = j.Department};
            return query.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I strongly suspect that's just the order the database decides to pick them up in - especially if it's using an index. Have you checked the query? Also, use a `List<int>` or something similar to avoid having to specify all those parameters...

Comment: LINQ isn't doing this -- SQL Server is.  It is optimizing the order based on indexes and information it has available about the data.  Since you don't provide an order, it leaves the order in its query order.

Comment: Side note: if you are going to pass 10 int parameters, all meaning the same thing (Employee IDs), why don't you just pass an array of ints and use Contains as so: `where empIdsArray.Contains(e.EmployeeNo)` It will do the same thing and your code will be cleaner/more maintenable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the following:

```
var employeeIds = new List<int> { empID1, empID2, empID3, empID4, empID5, empID6, empID7, empID8, empID9, empID10 };

var query = from e in context.EmployeeMasters
            join j in context.JobClasses on e.JobClass equals j.JobClass
            where employeeIds.Contains(e.EmployeeNo)
            select new queryClass {
              firstName = e.FirsName, 
              lastName = e.LastName, 
              employeeNo = e.EmployeeNo, 
              department = j.Department,
              orderNum = e.EmployeeNo == empID1 ? 1 :
                         e.EmployeeNo == empID2 ? 2 :
                         e.EmployeeNo == empID3 ? 3 :
                         e.EmployeeNo == empID4 ? 4 :
                         e.EmployeeNo == empID5 ? 5 :
                         e.EmployeeNo == empID6 ? 6 :
                         e.EmployeeNo == empID7 ? 7 :
                         e.EmployeeNo == empID8 ? 8 :
                         e.EmployeeNo == empID9 ? 9 :
                         e.EmployeeNo == empID10 ? 10 : 11
            };
return query.OrderBy(x => x.orderNum).ToArray();
```

Add a custom order property that will be set based on the value's order in the parameters. A little bit ugly, but meets the requirements based on your signature for this function (I also added the `employeeIds` `List<int>` above to make your query more readable).

Comment: What kind of sort would I add for it though? Say for example my inputs are 7165, 2341, 8951, 7164, 7163, 5214, 7154, 7416, 2645, 9120 (each of these aligning with empID1, empID2, etc.). Currently it would sort them in descedning order when I actually need them in the order I put them in. In this case empID1, empID2.. are tied to text fields and the order they are displayed on the next page is important.

Comment: If you need to display them in the order that they are going in, then add an `identity` field to the table that will auto-increment its integer value for each new field, or add a `CreateDate` field to the table that will set the date time when the row was inserted. Without specifying an explicit sort, you can't be guaranteed that sql server will return the rows in the order that you want.

Comment: @YaakovEllis I think he means in the order in which he entered them on the screen, not the order in which they were entered in the database.

Comment: I'm not in a position to add fields to these tables. Is there no other way?

Comment: @Danger_Fox updated my answer based on my new understanding of your question

Comment: @YaakovEllis I tried to implement that code but I get an error around the "e.EmployeeNo == empID10 ? 10 :" stating that it's expecting an expression. Also, that orderNum isn't valid and it needs to have a type, but I don't know what to declare it as.

Comment: @Danger_Fox I had an extra `:` on the last row from copy/paste. I think that that is what messed it up. Try it now please.